# Designing a REST service for media conversion

Tags: web-services, rest, mime-types

My current task is to design a REST service that can be used to convert from one media type to another (e.g. from video/x-msvieo to video/x-flv). Its not supposed to be usable vie Browser.
Generally, I'll let clients POST media files and return them some URL for further reference (like http://www.example.com/Media/12345).

Interesting thing is - and that's where questions arise - that the conversion process could be interpreted in two different ways:

1) A converted media is simply a different representation of the original one, so to request a media in a new format, you could just GET http://example.com/Media/12345, and tell the service in the Accept-header what format you need. Since converting for example a big video, the service would respond with a 202 Accepted until conversion has finished. But what should happen, if the conversion fails for any reason?

2) Since conversion takes such a long time, one could represent the process as its own resource. In this case, one would have to POST some form of job description (probably xml) to http://example.com/Media/12345 and the service would respond with a new URI for the requested conversion (like http://example.com/Media/12345/jobs/1). But wouldn't this kind of design be quite non-REST-linke?

What I currently have is this:

1.) POST media file to http://example.com/Media
2.) Response: 201 Created / Location: http://example.com/Media/12345
3.) GET http://example.com/Media/12345
4.) Response: 200 Ok and xml like this:

```
<media id="123457">
    <link xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="http://example.com/Media/12345/video/x-flv">video/x-flv</link>
    <link xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="http://example.com/Media/12345/video/mpeg">video/mpeg</link>
</media>
```

The links in the xml send you to conversion targets available for this media.

5.) Select from the links in the xml to start a conversion / get the result by GETting http://example.com/Media/12345/video/mpeg
6.) Response: 202 Accepted / Location: http://example.com/Media/12345/video/mpeg/Status
7.) Repeat step 5 until conversion is done or have a look at the http://example.com/Media/12345/video/mpeg/Status to see what currently happens.

So, thanks a lot for reading all this stuff :)
What do you think about my approach? What would you do differently?
I am quite new to this stuff, so any suggestions are highly appreciated.

kind regards: Bill

Answer (score 2):

In step 4 I would consider using a 300 response code.  You are doing something very similar to client driven content negotiation.  See how it's done here http://www.w3.org/TR/wd-xptr

Your idea to create a "job" resource to represent the creation of the new media file is a perfectly valid and very common approach to handling long running operations in RESTful systems.

The only other comment is that in step 5, I was initially concerned about using GET to do that, but having thought about it a bit more it does seem reasonable.  It's nice because the the final converted video can be made available at the same URL.  Then all the client has to do is be aware of the fact that if they request a video and they get a 202, they just have to wait a bit before retrying.  If they want, they can check the ./status resource to know if it done.  I guess you just have to make sure if you are already in the process of converting you return another 202 but don't start a new conversion process :-)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I wasn't aware of the 300 response. I'll have a closer look on that on monday :)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the redirect (presumably) to http://example.com/Media/12345/jobs/1 doesn’t sound very restful. It sounds like you are trying to implement an asynchronous service through a synchronous interface. Couldn’t you POST a ‘conversion request’ resource to kick the process of that returns a session, i.e. a bit like:

```
Class ConversionRequest
{
 Guid sessionid
  Int status
…
}
```

Then use a GET/sessionId to check the status of the conversion? In my experience, if a restful interface starts to feel complex it generally means the resource isn’t right for the task in hand.

Comment: Thanks for answering :)
>  It sounds like you are trying to implement an asynchronous service through a synchronous interface.
Yes, as far as I understand, that's exactly what I'm supposed to do :)
On your suggestions: I am very sorry, but I don't really understand what you mean.
Do you, with "if a restful interface starts to feel complex it generally means the resource isn’t right for the task in hand." mean that using SOAP would be the better way to do it?
Also, could you comment on my current design (the steps 1-7)?

Comment: I’m saying changing the resource to simplify, I’m not saying use SOAP (perish the thought!). From my understanding your resource ‘Media’ models a media object, i.e. a video file, etc but I don’t believe that is a suitable REST resource. I am saying the resource is a ‘conversion-request’ or ‘conversion’. Traditional OO-type objects do not necessarily fit that well in the REST world, as you only have post/put/get/del operations. So, I simplified conversion would look something like:

Comment: 1. Client: POST a conversion-request resource. 2. Server: Add conversion request to queue, flagged as status=pending. Returns 200-ok with a unique session id in the response conversion-request resource.
3.Background process: processes conversions in the queue, updating a status flag
4. Client: polls conversion-request resource with session id until the conversion-request resource status is complete (ie complete-with-errors or complete-success)

Comment: What is not restful about a redirect to  http://example.com/Media/12345/jobs/1 ? The job is a resource which can be referenced or redirected to.

Answer (score 0):

You approach seems fine. You can encode any concept in your URIs which obviously includes the *jobs concept*. It all depends on how you want to design your application interface (resources).

Here is one way I would attack it and it might give you some ideas. (It depends on your clients and **application protocol / interface** :

- /media

  - GET - List of media + status etc.
  - POST - Add medias + returns **Location:** /media/{number}/jobs/{number}
- /media/{number}

  - GET - Shows media status (Valid,In Progress), formats etc. Links to default/current jobs
- /media/{number}/jobs

  - GET - List of jobs
  - POST - Do extra/special conversion
- /media/{number}/formats/{name}

  - GET - Download
  - PUT - Start specific conversion, redirects to a job.
- /media/{number}/jobs/{number} - Job status etc.

  - GET - Status etc,
  - DELETE - Cancel job

Remember that PUT and DELETE is idempotent and POST not.

The way you make use of **hypermedia and links** looks good. The client should discover the next step or related information via links and not rely on out of band information such as URI structure.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'll have a closer look on monday :)